# Difference between the questions 「男じゃないんですか？」 and 「男じゃないですか？」

Tags: questions, phrase-requests

I was wondering if there is a difference if you add that ん. Is the first one correct and the second one not?

> 男じゃ**ないん**ですか？
>
> 男じゃ**ない**ですか？

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Difference between noun phrase + なの/ですか/なんですか](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18400/) Strongly related: [Use of ～のか and ～んですか in questions not seeking a yes no answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/506/)

Comment: But in this case ん is not a statement, is a question, I was asking if the way of asking needs that ん. This question neither is なんですか？　or　んです。

Comment: I'm sorry if I changed the intention of your question. But let me try to explain why I thought these questions are similar: The general pattern is `sentence+の/ん+copula+か`. If the `sentence` ends on the copula だ, it becomes な, giving なのか or なのですか/なんですか. If it ends on the negated copula じゃない, you get じゃないのか or じゃないのですか/じゃないんですか. As I understood it, the question was about the presence of ん/の, not the negated phrase before it.

Comment: 一例ですが、「あれ？もしかして、あの人、男じゃないですか？」って言うとき(今気づいた時など)に、「男じゃないですか？」って言うと思います。誰かが「あの女の人は~~~。」とか言ったことに対して「えっ？あの人は、男じゃないんですか？（男ですよね！？）」 って言うときには「男じゃないんですか？」って言うと思います。

Comment: 厳密に言えば、両文とも、イントネーションによって意味やニュアンスが変わるような気がしますが、発音の説明はしにくいので、今回はパスで・・　真面目に考えていると気が変になりそうなタイプの質問です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference is how long you assumed that the person is a man. 「男じゃない**ん**ですか？」 implies that you've been assuming that the person is a man for some time. On the other hand, 「男じゃないですか？」 implies that you have just realized that the person is a man (though, it depends on the emphasis. You would put the emphasis on the word 「ない」 in this case).

Comment: This use of ん applies for every negative question with ない, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so (at least I can't think of a counterexample off the top of my head). I might also add that ないんですか？ is an informal version of ないのですか？.