# What is the difference between kattan and kaimashita?

Tags: grammar

In Japanese the mashita ending is the past form of polite verbs.

[For example](http://www.japaneseverbconjugator.com/VerbDetails.asp?txtVerb=%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%86):

```
To buy (root form) - Kau
To buy (polite form) - kaimasu 
To buy (polite form, past) - kaimashita
```

In my Japanese text book it has the following example

```
Where did you buy it?
Doko de kattan desu ka?
```

Why is the speaker using `kattan` instead of `kaimashita` (especially as `kattan` is defined as [coal](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A4%90%E7%82%AD))?
Could `kattan` be substituted with `kaimashita`?
How does the meaning change when using `kattan` or `kaimashita`?

Comment: katta is the informal past tense of kau. For the 'n' part try looking up the phrase 'explanatory の' and see this question http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/506/use-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b-in-questions-not-seeking-a-yes-no-answer

Comment: And this: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010 If you're okay, I think this can be closed as a duplicate of either of these questions.

Comment: @naruto So is the speaker using `kattan` (instead of `Kaimashita`) to be more informal and to soften the question so it's not so demanding. And so, yes, you can switch it with `Kaimashita`?. But then does that mean it is always better to use `n  desu` forms to avoid sounding rude when asking questions? Is that correct? Also, is to buy another meaning of `Kattan`? (In addition to coal?) Thanks!

Comment: You're misunderstanding the parse. nda/ndesu is a contraction of noda/nodesu, which @user3856370 linked above.

Comment: @big_smile (1) Kattan is not a conjugation form. It's `katta` (ta-form) + `no` (contracted to `n`) + `desu` + `ka`. (2) Neither is milder nor politer than the other. `no/n` has an important role and omitting it would sound very awkward. Please read the linked answers carefully.

Answer (score -1):

> To buy (root form) - Kau
> To buy (polite form) - kaimasu, (casual form) - kau
> To buy (polite form, past) - kaimashita, (casual form, past) - katta
>
> Where did you buy it?
> Doko de kattan desu ka? = Doko de katta no desu ka?

"Katta" is a casual and past form, but "katta no desu ka?" is a polit form because it has "desu."

"Kattan desu (ka?)" is a short form of "Katta no desu (ka?)"

> Doko de kattan desu ka? = Doko de kai mashita ka?

Both are polite. The latter is more polite. The former is a spoken vocabulary.

Comment: Dear the person who gamve me negative evaluation, I'd like to know why. Or I can't improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I think your answer is helpful. `The former is a spoken vocabulary.` Does that mean the latter (`kai mashita`) wouldn't sound as natural as when spoken (e.g. the former is better to use when speaking). Is that correct? Thanks!